# How to create an user control without graphic using c#

Tags: c#

How to create an user control without graphic?

When I create an user control using `Windows Form Control Library`, I saw this command line:  `public partial class UserControl1: UserControl`.
My friend told me to replace `UserControl1: UserControl` with `UserControl1:Component,IDisposable`.
I don't know what `Component,IDisposable` is.

Comment: Wouldn't a UserControl without graphics be a Class?

Comment: It is not a class, it is a UserControl which I can add to ToolBox and drag and drog into form

Comment: @John3136 no, think Windows.Forms.Timer

Comment: Blorgbeard, correct, the same to timer

Comment: @Blorgbeard - Timer isn't a UserControl - UserControl has properties specifically related to appearance. Timer is a Component - perhaps tha6t is what you need rather than a UserControl?

Comment: Yeah @John3136 that's what I meant. OP wants a "user defined control" rather than a UserControl specifically, I guess.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can see what your friend is talking about if you take a look at one of the other components you can drop onto your Form that don't have their own interface:

```
public class BackgroundWorker : Component

public class ErrorProvider : Component, IExtenderProvider, ISupportInitialize

public class Timer : Component
```

You can easily create your own:

```
public class MyVeryOwnComponent : Component
{
    public string Setting1 { get; set; }
    public string Setting2 { get; set; }

    public void SomeImportantMethodYouCanCall()
    {
       // ...
    }
}
```

And drop it on your Form: *(you'll have to rebuild first, to get it to show in the Toolbox)*

[image]

Comment: Did you use `Windows Form Control Libary` to create myVeryOwnComponent1 ??

Comment: Yes, I know, Thank you so much for your helps

Answer (score 2):

What you are talking about is a "Component" which is any class derived from [`System.ComponentModel.Component`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.component(v=vs.110).aspx). A control is a special type of component which derives from the class [`System.Windows.Forms.Control`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control(v=vs.110).aspx).

If you want to make your own component just make your class derive from `Component`, which is what your friend did with the `:Component,IDisposable`. The IDisposable part was not needed because `Component` already implements `IDisposeable` and could be left off.